# Надёжный установщик сертификатов X509

Tags: x509, c#, wix

Для шифрования данных на канальном уровне при работе через Интернет мы используем сертификаты X509. Разворачивание этих сертификатов по инструкции, прилагаемой к нашей продукции - процесс весьма муторный.

Все попытки написать батники или утилиты для автоматизации этой работы не увенчались успехом, т.к. все они обычно работают только на той машине, на которой разрабатываются. Всякие консольные утилиты типа makecert тоже работают только в своей версии Windows.

Может, существуют какие-нибудь библиотеки, которые предоставляют уровень абстракции над зависимостью сертификатов от окружения? Их необходимо встроить либо в приложение, написанное на C#, либо в инсталлятор WIX.

Требования у нас такие.

- Пользователь должен иметь возможность создать сертификат, введя имя файла через диалог сохранения файла и пароль. Создаваемый сертификат должен быть связан с нашим корневым центром сертификации.
- Импортировать либо свой сертификат, либо созданный на предыдущем шаге, в хранилище "Доверенные лица" локального компьютера. При этом, если ещё не создан, должен автоматически создасться наш корневой центр сертификации в соответствующем хранилище.
- В зависимости от того, конфигурируется клиент или сервер, должен загружаться либо файл .cer, либо .pfx.
- Если пользователь при импорте сертификата ввёл неправильный пароль, надо это внятно сообщить, без всяких "process {0} exited with code -1".

То есть, пользователь должен иметь возможность сконфигурировать сертификаты одной кнопкой при наличии готового сертификата. Создать сертификат тоже должна быть возможность одной кнопкой.

Comment: "Создаваемый сертификат должен быть связан с нашим корневым центром сертификации." -- т.е. должен быть подписан вашим центром? (т.е. это уже телодвижения центра). А так -- писать. На чём -- ваш выбор. Возможно поможет openssl.net (http://openssl-net.sourceforge.net), ну и изучение openssl при этом неизбежно.

Comment: Ну, центр у нас тоже представляет собой три файла формата pvk, pfx и cer, которые идут в комплект поставки продукта.

Comment: Ну краткий пример работы с сертификатами в openssl (из ком. строки) есть в http://citforum.ru/security/cryptography/openssl/
Менее краткий -- в man'ах

Comment: Такое ощущение, что автор статьи по ссылке не умеет говорить по-русски. Как её понимать??

Comment: @Modus Возможно. Но тогда можете посмотреть на труд, где авторы вообще по русски ни слова не написали Network Security with OpenSSL
By Pravir Chandra, Matt Messier, John Viega, O'Reily, 2002 А более конкретные вопросы будут?

Comment: Кстати, в каком виде оно вас больше интересует? openssl предоставляет API, а кроме того есть утилита openssl, позволяющая выполнять эти операции из командной строки.

Comment: Лучше API. Документация по openssl.NET вроде бы более читабельная.

Comment: Тогда книга. Не знаю, насколько это законно, но сети она лежит.